# Split and then pretty Print xml to be stored in a List

Tags: python, lxml

I have file called Books.xml
The Books.xml is **huge 2Gb** with structure similar to this

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Detail ID="67">
            <BookName>Code Complete 2</BookName>
            <Author>Steve McConnell</Author>
            <Pages>960</Pages>
            <ISBN>0735619670</ISBN>        
            <BookName>Application Architecture Guide 2</BookName>
            <Author>Microsoft Team</Author>
            <Pages>496</Pages>
            <ISBN>073562710X</ISBN>
        </Detail>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Detail ID="87">
            <BookName>Rocking Python</BookName>
            <Author>Guido Rossum</Author>
            <Pages>960</Pages>
            <ISBN>0735619690</ISBN>
            <BookName>Python Rocks</BookName>
            <Author>Microsoft Team</Author>
            <Pages>496</Pages>
            <ISBN>073562710X</ISBN>
        </Detail>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

I have tried to split it on the Book tag like this

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
filename = r'D:\test\Books.xml'
context = iter(etree.iterparse(filename, events=('start', 'end')))
_, root = next(context)
for event, elem in context:
    if event == 'start' and elem.tag == 'Book':
        print(etree.dump(elem))
        root.clear()
```

I get the result like this

```
<Book>
        <Detail ID="67">
            <BookName>Code Complete 2</BookName>
            <Author>Steve McConnell</Author>
            <Pages>960</Pages>
            <ISBN>0735619670</ISBN>
            <BookName>Application Architecture Guide 2</BookName>
            <Author>Microsoft Team</Author>
            <Pages>496</Pages>
            <ISBN>073562710X</ISBN>
        </Detail>
    </Book>

None
<Book>
        <Detail ID="87">
            <BookName>Rocking Python</BookName>
            <Author>Guido Rossum</Author>
            <Pages>960</Pages>
            <ISBN>0735619690</ISBN>
            <BookName>Python Rocks</BookName>
            <Author>Microsoft Team</Author>
            <Pages>496</Pages>
            <ISBN>073562710X</ISBN>
        </Detail>
    </Book>
None
```

1. How do i get rid of the **None**
2. I would like to store the fragments broken up on book into some sort
   of queue  and then have another program dequeue it.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=etree+pretty+print

Comment: Hi Karoly thanks but i need to pretty print the fragment that i have extracted not the whole document that i read from the disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how it can be done with [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) for inter process queueing and [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) for manipulating, serializing and pretty printing a given xml:

```
#tasks.py file
from lxml import etree
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def print_book(book_xml):
    book = etree.fromstring(book_xml)
    # do something interesting ...
    print(etree.tostring(book, pretty_print=True))

#caller.py file
from tasks import print_book
from lxml import etree

for _, book in etree.iterparse('Books.xml', tag="Book"):
    book_xml = etree.tostring(book)
    print_book.delay(book_xml)
```

Comment: I will look up celery thanks but my file is 1Gb i cant use etree.parse

Comment: right, answer updated, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856163/using-lxml-and-iterparse-to-parse-a-big-1gb-xml-file

Comment: Wow amazing Guy.Mind explaining me what print_book.delay is doing there

Comment: it put the function call as a message in the queue to be consumed latter by celery workers, follow celery tutorials for further info