# How to solve an OverflowError when parsing a large XML?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to parse an XML file using the [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) Python package. However, I am getting an `OverflowError`, perhaps because of the XML is large (~2GB). I did see that this question was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789917/overflowerror-size-does-not-fit-in-an-int-while-parsing-big-xml-with-dom). The answers mostly suggest that perhaps a 32-bit Python is used. But mine is certainly 64-bit, as it also reports when I start up my interpreter.

Here are the lines of code I run:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlPath = os.path.join(codePath, 'data', 'nonmeta', name + '.xml')
xml_data = open(xmlPath, encoding="utf8").read()
root = ET.XML(xml_data)
```

The last row produces the following exception:

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1314, in
>   XML
>       parser.feed(text)
>
> OverflowError: size does not fit in an int

I am working in Windows 7 on Python 3.6.0, using an IPython 5.1.0 as an interpreter. Any suggestions on what can be done to parse the data without getting this error?

**EDIT: why I believe that it's not a 32-bit issue**
The operating system is windows 7. When viewing the computer properties, it says:

> System type: 64-bit Operating System

And when I start up my Ipython interpreter , using Spyder, the start-up message says:

> Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016,
>   11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] Type "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.
>
> IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Comment: size fit for an int? that seems like a 32 bit system to me. no?

Comment: Thanks @vtd-xml-author. I added in an edit why I'm quite sure that it's not a 32-bit system.

Comment: could it be that the elementtree module is compiled in 32 bit mode?

Comment: did you try just parsing the file `ET.parse(xmlPath)`?

Comment: or `iterparse` as suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789917/) to the question you mentioned