# Converting GraphML file to another

Tags: python, performance, lxml, graphml, iterparse

Hi I have a simple graphML file and I would like to remove the node tag from the GraphML and save it in another GraphML file. The GraphML size is 3GB below given is the sample.

Input File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.1/graphml.xsd">
    <key id="weight" for="edge" attr.name="weight" attr.type="string"></key>
    <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
        <node id="1"></node>
        <node id="2">
        </node>
        <node id="3">
        </node>
        <node id="4">
        </node>
        <node id="5">
        </node>
        <edge id="6" source="1" target="2">
            <data key="weight">3</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="7" source="2" target="4">
            <data key="weight">1</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="8" source="2" target="3">
            <data key="weight">9</data>
        </edge>
    </graph>
</graphml>
```

Required Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.1/graphml.xsd">
    <key id="weight" for="edge" attr.name="weight" attr.type="string"></key>
    <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
        <edge id="6" source="1" target="2">
            <data key="weight">3</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="7" source="2" target="4">
            <data key="weight">1</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="8" source="2" target="3">
            <data key="weight">9</data>
        </edge>
    </graph>
</graphml>
```

Are there any methods to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a python module to deal with graphml.
Curiously, the [documentation](http://hadim.fr/pygraphml/reference.html#) has no `remove` or `delete` function.

Since graphml is xml markup, you could use an xml module instead.
I've used [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) and liked it very much.
This module allows you to load xml code to a python object. After modifying the object, you can save it back to xml.

If `data` is a string containing the xml:

```
data_object=xmltodict.parse(data)
del data_object["graphml"]["graph"]["node"]
xmltodict.unparse(data_object, pretty=True)
```

This removes the `node` entries, the unparse will return a string with xml.

If the structure of the xml becomes more complex, you'll need to search for the nodes in the `data_object`. But that shouldn't be a problem, it's just an ordered dictionary.

Another problem might be the size of the xml. 3GB is a lot.
xmltodict does support a streaming mode for large files, but that is something I've never used.

Comment: Actually, the problem is the file size. I have used [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) python library to do the same task.

Answer (score 1):

After some reading some Link I came up with the solution of iterative parsing. Bt I can't figure out the difference between simple parse and iterparse in terms of RAM usage.

Important Links :
 - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/
 - [using lxml and iterparse() to parse a big (+- 1Gb) XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856163/using-lxml-and-iterparse-to-parse-a-big-1gb-xml-file)

Code :

import lxml.etree as et

```
graphml = {  
   "graph": "{http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns}graph",  
   "node": "{http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns}node",  
   "edge": "{http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns}edge",  
   "data": "{http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns}data",  
   "weight": "{http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns}data[@key='weight']",  
   "edgeid": "{http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns}data[@key='edgeid']"  
}



for event, elem in et.iterparse("/data/sample.graphml",tag=graphml.get("edge"), events = ('end', )):  
    print(et.tostring(elem))
    elem.clear()
    while elem.getprevious() is not None:
        del elem.getparent()[0]
```