# Python: Read a very large XML file

Tags: python, xml

Am trying to read an xml file(which is a french diccionary) from a python script, but am getting the error below. Is there anyway I can fix it?
PS: the file is 158 643 Ko

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parse("Dic.xml")

Data = doc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
titleData = Data.firstChild.data
print (titleData)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    doc = minidom.parse("Morphalou-2.0.xml")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 924, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(fp)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 204, in parseFile
    buffer = file.read(16*1024)
MemoryError
```

Advance Thanks

Comment: probably wont help, but use ElementTree.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the file I want to read is too big, isn't it?

Comment: I have never dealt with XML files that big. I can't guarantee it would work, but have you tried lxml ?

Comment: Try lxml. Search for iterparse. Clean the part when you don't need it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856163/using-lxml-and-iterparse-to-parse-a-big-1gb-xml-file

Comment: iterparse worked fine, Thanks