# Parsing Xml files >3gb using lxml etree iterparse

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, iterparse

I am not able to parse XML file of huge size using lxml tree. What I came to know from my research is that lxml iterparse loads the xml file until it gets tag which it is looking for.
This is snippet of my code :-

```
for event, child in etree.iterparse(xml_file,tag='test'):
        print(sys.getsizeof(child))
```

It is not even reaching print statement and is getting killed. Any help on this matter?

Comment: XML is a tree structure and to parse it properly you need a stateful parser. That requires a lot of resources. While `iterparse` is more memory efficient than other parsing strategies it will still require a lot of RAM to parse 3 GB. Or seen from the other perspective: it's not a great idea to create huge XML files.

Comment: I am running above code on server. I understand that it will require lot of RAM, but is there any way to parse such huge file?

Comment: Another useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193997/1566221