# How to read large xml files using pandas read_xml API?

Tags: pandas, xml, memory

I am trying to read a large XML file. The file size is around 84 GB, Stack overflow data dump from "Post.xml"

I noticed there is Pandas API pandas.read_xml() [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html). But if I try to use this then it gives me "memory error"

```html
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-86c9119d39ba> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_xml(posts_file)

~\anaconda3\envs\analytics\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\xml.py in read_xml(path_or_buffer, xpath, namespaces, elems_only, attrs_only, names, encoding, parser, stylesheet, compression, storage_options)
    925     """
    926 
--> 927     return _parse(
    928         path_or_buffer=path_or_buffer,
    929         xpath=xpath,

~\anaconda3\envs\analytics\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\xml.py in _parse(path_or_buffer, xpath, namespaces, elems_only, attrs_only, names, encoding, parser, stylesheet, compression, storage_options, **kwargs)
    726         raise ValueError("Values for parser can only be lxml or etree.")
    727 
--> 728     data_dicts = p.parse_data()
    729 
    730     return _data_to_frame(data=data_dicts, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\envs\analytics\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\xml.py in parse_data(self)
    389         from lxml.etree import XML
    390 
--> 391         self.xml_doc = XML(self._parse_doc(self.path_or_buffer))
    392 
    393         if self.stylesheet is not None:

~\anaconda3\envs\analytics\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\xml.py in _parse_doc(self, raw_doc)
    540         )
    541 
--> 542         handle_data = get_data_from_filepath(
    543             filepath_or_buffer=raw_doc,
    544             encoding=self.encoding,

~\anaconda3\envs\analytics\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\xml.py in get_data_from_filepath(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, storage_options)
    611         ) as handle_obj:
    612             filepath_or_buffer = (
--> 613                 handle_obj.handle.read()
    614                 if hasattr(handle_obj.handle, "read")
    615                 else handle_obj.handle

MemoryError:
```

I could not find any options to read the xml file chuck chuck. Can anyone suggest how can I overcome this limitations?

### *** Updated ***

As it turns out panda's read_xml() can not parse a XML file larger than 1 GB even if the system has 100GB RAM.

So, I ended up implementing parsing the XML file in a iterative way. The code is shared below. I hope this will help someone.

```
def save_df(df, file_name, append=False):
    if append:
        df.to_csv(file_name, index=False, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, mode="a", header=False)
    else:
        df.to_csv(file_name, index=False, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

def append_to_file(rows, output_csv_file, append):
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    df.drop_duplicates('Id', inplace=True)
    save_df(df, output_csv_file, append=append)
    print("%d rows has been appended to the CSV file %s" % (len(df), output_csv_file))
    return len(df)


def convert_xml_to_csv_iteratively(XML_file, columns, output_csv_file, threshold):
if output_csv_file is None:
    output_csv_file = XML_file[:-4] + ".csv"

print("Going to Convert XML files to CSV file")
context = ET.iterparse(XML_file, events=("end",))

# Variables to process the output
total_questions = 0
unique_rows = 0
rows = []
cur_count = 0    
append = False

for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == "row":
        dic = {}
        for col in COLS:
            dic[col] = elem.attrib.get(col, '')
        rows.append(dic)
         # progress
        if total_questions % 100000 == 0:
            print('Total Questions: %d' % total_questions)
        elem.clear()
        total_questions += 1
        cur_count += 1
    if cur_count > threshold:
        unique_rows +=  append_to_file(rows, output_csv_file, append)
        append = True
        cur_count = 0
        rows = []
if(len(rows) > 0):
    unique_rows += append_to_file(rows, output_csv_file, append)
print("Total number of rows: %d vs unique_rows: %d" % (total_questions, unique_rows))
return total_questions
```

Comment: `pd.read_xml` is a new feature ([merged in Feb](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/39516)). There is an [issue tracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40131) for bugs and enhancements, but I don't see anything related to chunking. Not sure what the best way forward for you for the time being is though - good luck!

Comment: as a [very slow] workaround you can [use lxml's iterparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856163/using-lxml-and-iterparse-to-parse-a-big-1gb-xml-file), but I imagine that's a far cry from what you're looking for in e.g. `pd.read_xml(..., chunksize=1e6)` :/

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, Thanks for the suggestions, currently I am using xml.etree.ElementTree's iterparse to get the task done and as you mentioned this is excruciatingly slow for a dataset this size.